# JDBC: Is SQL code executed via the PreparedStatement static SQL?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, static, prepared-statement

Per definition static SQL code is preprocessed and linked to a database-resident module during a bind phase, while dynamic SQL is compiled and checked during runtime. JDBC offers PreparedStatements for parameterized queries. Is SQL code executed via PreparedStatements static SQL or dynamic SQL? Is this database dependent? One the one hand PreparedStatements were intended to have the advantages of static SQL, on the other hand, after (Java) program execution finished, the handle will be lost.

Comment: preparing a statement "compiles" the query, so the db merely has to stuff in parameters' values at run-/query-time. it becomes semi-static in that you can reuse that same statement without having to go through a recompile phase. but yes, the preparation will be lost when the db connection is closed.

Comment: Whose definition is that? Your definition sounds more like wat I'd call embedded SQL.